How to assert number present in accessibilityValue in Earlgrey framework using swift
EarlGrey.selectElement(with: grey_accessibilityValue("3 items")).assert(grey_sufficientlyVisible())

in this grey_accessibilityValue '3' is present and i want to fetch that number OR i want to assert whether there is any number is present with 'items'
Example: In Espresso/java we will write
onView(withText(CustomRegexMatcher.regexMatcherWithString("You have.*\\d+ items in this series."))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

i tried with below modifications
EarlGrey.selectElement(with: grey_accessibilityValue("\\d+ items")).assert(grey_sufficientlyVisible())

EarlGrey.selectElement(with: grey_accessibilityValue(".* items")).assert(grey_sufficientlyVisible())


Anyone help me if you know
